# Python = Turning User Input Into a Sentence

Tags: python

Below I made a program that asks you three different questions and summarizes it all in one sentence. The way I tried it below gave me an error and when I put the `+ choice +choice2 + choice3` all at the end, the user inputs answers get piled at the end. How am I supposed to put three user inputs, spread out, in specific locations of the sentence?

```
choice = input("What is your favorite food?")
choice2 = input("What is your favorite color?")
choice3 = input("What is your favorite car?")

print("So your favorite food is " + choice "and your favorite color is " + choice2 "and your favorite car is " + choice3)
```

I have done some research on this website [Python User Input](http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~schmidt/200s08/Lectures/999.summary.html) but still could not find an answer to my question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're missing two `+` symbols

Answer (score 1):

change print statement

```
print("So your favorite food is " + choice + "and your favorite color is " + choice2 +"and your favorite car is " + choice3)
```

or much cleaner solution is using fstrings

```
print(f"So your favorite food is {choice} and your favorite color is {choice2} and your favorite car is {choice3}")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you posted above is almost correct, but you missed two + operators (after choice and choice2.

```
print("So your favorite food is " + choice + "and your favorite color is " + choice2 + "and your favorite car is " + choice3)
```

A better way of formatting strings is by using the string formatting syntax.

The old-style is:

```
print("So your favorite food is %s and your favorite color is %s and your favorite car is %s" % (choice, choice2, choice3))
```

The more modern Python syntax for string formatting is:

```
print("So your favorite food is {c1} and your favorite color is {c2} and your favorite car is {c3}".format(c1=choice, c2=choice2, c3=choice3))
```

More about string formatting [here](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `+` operator. Change your code to `print("So your favorite food is " + choice + " and your favorite color is " + choice2 + " and your favorite car is " + choice3)`

When `+` operator gets sandwiched by 2 `string`s, then it concatenate the `string`s.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer formatting string for cleaner approach like following:

```
print("So your favorite food is {} and your favorite color is {} and your favorite car is {}".format(choice, choice2, choice3))
```